# When is it safe to compare doubles using standard < in a map/sort?

Tags: c++, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Floating point keys in std:map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684573/floating-point-keys-in-stdmap)

Well I know there are cases where you want to provide a special function for doing doubles comparison. Such cases could include times when you do arithmetic operations because you get rounding in the floating point arithmetic.

However are there times when it is safe to use < or > to compare doubles?

Let's say I have list of doubles that are calculated once that I need to sort or use as a key in a map (ie. std::map) and I guarantee that there aren't any additional arithmetic operations afterwards.

Can I guarantee that my sort order will be correct if I traverse the collection using iterators?

I'm thinking I can get more performance this way.

Comment: I'm confused, why wouldn't it be safe? Are you thinking of `==`?

Comment: Inequality comparisons should be fine... equality comparison is what people generally warn about.

Comment: @Pubby: A map needs to know equality, so it's not safe to have floating point keys even though it's using `operator<`

Comment: @MooingDuck - it's **safe** to use doubles. If you don't know how good your values are, you may well find that your results are incorrect. That's not the container's fault.

Comment: @oldrinb - yes, you hear warnings about testing for equality, because that's what people notice. But ordering comparisons have the same "problem": if you don't know whether you've lost or gained a bit or two you not only get surprising results for equality tests, you get surprising results for ordering tests.

Comment: @PeteBecker right, but the problem is generally that strict equality without some tolerance (epsilon) yields surprising results...

Comment: As does <, for **exactly** the same reason. Using a tolerance is an advanced technique; it greatly complicates logic when a "equals" b and b "equals" c but a does not "equal" c.

Answer (score 5):

It's always safe to use `<` to compare `double` values in a `std::map`, as long as you never add any NaN values.  The comparison used for the map must be a *strict weak ordering*, which has these requirements (C++03 §23.1.2/2 and §25.3/3-4):

- Define `equiv(a, b)` as `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`.  Then, both `<` and `equiv` must be transitive relations:

  1. If `a < b` and `b < c`, then `a < c` must be true
  2. If `equiv(a, b)` and `equiv(b, c)`, then `equiv(a, c)` must be true

`double` value comparisons certainly satisfy these axioms, *except* when NaN values are thrown into the mix.  NaNs have the strange property that they are unequal to all values (including themselves!) but not less than or greater than anything:

```
NaN < 0    // false
NaN <= 0   // false
NaN == 0   // false
NaN > 0    // false
NaN >= 0   // false
NaN != 0   // true
NaN < NaN  // false
NaN <= NaN // false
NaN == NaN // false (!!!)
NaN > NaN  // false
NaN >= NaN // false
NaN != NaN // true (!!!)
```

This causes problems, because under the rules above, `NaN` has the property that `equiv(x, NaN)` is true for all `x`, which by transitivity implies that all values are equivalent, except non-NaN values are clearly not equivalent.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer got down-voted. It's the only one that's correct.

Comment: Ayep -- good answer here!  So you could fix this problem by ordering everything that does not equal itself lowest?  Ie, something like `struct NaNSafeLess { bool operator()(double left, double right) const { bool leftNaN = left!=left; bool rightNaN = right!=right; return (leftNaN!=rightNaN)?leftNaN<rightNaN:left<right; } };`?

Comment: @Yakk: Yeah, I think that would work.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use standard `operator<` in a set or a map.  Most fuzzy `double` comparators are not strict enough to be used in a `map` or `set`.  (And hope to hell that you aren't messing around with floating point modes while accessing said map...)

I would advise to use `multimap` or `multiset`, because two values you think are equal might be slightly different.  If you are already expecting multiple entries, you should handle almost-equal entries much better.

Next, when searching for a hit do `lower_bound(x - epsilon)` and `upper_bound(x + epsilon)` in order to catch entries in the map that aren't where you think they are.

Ie, here is "is this `double` in this `multiset<double>`" code:

```
typedef std::multiset<double> double_set;
std::pair< double_set::iterator, double_set::iterator >
get_equal_range( double_set& s, double d, double epsilon = 0.00001 )
{
  auto lower = s.lower_bound( d-epsilon );
  auto upper = s.upper_bound( d+epsilon );
  return std::make_pair( lower, upper );
}
std::pair< double_set::const_iterator, double_set::const_iterator >
get_equal_range( double_set const& s, double d, double epsilon = 0.00001 )
{
  auto lower = s.lower_bound( d-epsilon );
  auto upper = s.upper_bound( d+epsilon );
  return std::make_pair( lower, upper );
}
bool TestMembership( double_set const& s, double d, double epsilon = 0.00001 )
{
  auto range = get_equal_range( s, d, epsilon );
  return range.first != range.second;
}
```

So a given `double` could map to a range of entries, or have more than 1 hit in the `set`.

Stolen from a great answer below: Default double `operator<` will screw your `map` or `set` up if you pass `NaN` in.

When putting things into `map` and `set` (and multi versions), you *must* maintain the strict weak ordering rules.  If you fail, you will get seemingly random crashes, and the occasional infinite loop: the code in `map` and `set` is not robust against ordering failure.

Comment: You use the `lower_bound` when looking for a hit.  Ie, instead of `set<double> s; auto it = s.find( 0.7 ); if (it != end()) { ... }`, you do a `set<double> s; auto lower = s.lower_bound( 0.7-epsilon ); auto upper = s.upper_bound( 0.7+epsilon ); if (lower != upper) { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

Using standard '<' in a map or set is vital, because any fudge factor you try to introduce will destroy the strict ordering they use to organize the container. Unfortunately this means that you might have trouble finding an element unless you have the exact value.

You can use `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` with values just below and above your desired search value to produce a range where the value must be.