# How to set VSCode for 64-bit compilation?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, compilation, 64-bit

The problem is the same as this:

[A program returns different results in two IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635546/a-c-program-returns-different-results-in-two-ide/64918072#64918072)

I have this same issue, but in VSCode, and in C language. How do I set it for 64-bit compilation?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    char string[20];
    printf("Informe o nome: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &string);

    double salario = 0;
    printf("Informe o salario: ");
    scanf("%lf", &salario);
    double salarioCopy = salario;

    if (salario > 4087.65) {
        salario = salario * 0.725;
    }
    else if (salario >= 3271.39) {
        salario = salario * 0.775;
    }
    else if (salario >= 2453.51) {
        salario = salario * 0.85;
    }
    else if (salario >= 1637.12) {
        salario = salario * 0.925;
    }
    else {
    }
    printf("\n%s ganha R$ %.2f, que apos abatido o IR, ficam R$ %.2f\n", string, salarioCopy, salario);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

f I input `10000`, the result in VSCode is: `9250`, while in a online IDE i get `7250`.

Can anybody help?

Comment: If I input 10000, the result in VSCode is: 9250, while in a online IDE i get 7250.

Comment: what `scanf("%lf", &salario)` returns? Did it read data successfully (returns `1`)? How long name do you type to input? It is possible that it is too long  (more then 19) and you have Undefined Behavior. Note that online ide is right.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of your C compiler, perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ? Did you read the documentation of your debugger, maybe [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) ? Did you read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) ? Are aware of [undefined behavior](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/undefined-behavior-c-cpp/) ?

Comment: Copy paste input and output for both cases so we have clear picture what have you typed in incorrectly.

Comment: Which online IDE?

Comment: You probably should tag this with C instead of C++.

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &string);` invokes *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type: `char*` is expected but `char(*)[20]` is passed. The `&` here should be removed.

Comment: Getting two different results from two different compilers means that (excluding the possibility of a compiler bug) [you have demons flying out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). P.S. This is not a C++ program. This is a C program.

Comment: Fix the undefined behaviour first. Then run through the code line by line. My money is on the `if` statements evaluating differently due to strict floating point being on or off.

Comment: after changing from MINGW to MINGW-64, it worked. Should i review the code anyway?

Comment: PVS-Studio error: V576 Incorrect format. Consider checking the second actual argument of the 'scanf' function. The pointer to string of char type symbols is expected. - https://godbolt.org/z/7vY3dh