# Validity of std::map::iterator after erasing elements

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, std, stdmap

I have written a code for solving the following problem: We have a `map<double,double>` with (relatively) huge number of items. We want to merge the adjacent items in order to reduce the size of the map keeping a certain "loss factor" as low as possible.

To do so, I first populate a list containing adjacent iterators and the associated loss factor (let's say each list element has the following type:

```
struct myPair {
    map<double,double>::iterator curr, next;
    double loss;
    myPair(map<double,double>::iterator c, map<double,double>::iterator n, 
        double l):  curr(c), next(n), loss(l) {}
};
```

).  This is done as follows:

```
for (map<double,double>::iterator it1 = myMap.begin(); it1 != --(myMap.end()); 
    it1++) {
    map<double,double>::iterator it2 = it1; it2++;
    double l = computeLoss(it1,it2); 
    List.push(myPair(it1,it2,l));
}
```

Then, I find the list element corresponding to the lowest loss factor, `erase` the corresponding elements from the `map` and `insert` a new element (result of merging `curr` and `next`) in the `map`. Since this also changes the list elements corresponding to the element after `next` or before `curr` I update the corresponding entries and also the associated loss factor.

(I don't get into the details of how to implement the above efficiently but basically I am combining a double linked list and a heap).

While the `erase` operations should not invalidate the remaining iterators for some specific input instances of the program I get the `double free or corruption` error exactly at the point where I attempt to erase the elements from the `map`.

I tried to track this and it seems this happens when both `first` and `second` entries of the two map elements are very close (more precisely when the `first`s of `curr` and `next` are very close).

A strange thing is that I put an `assert` while populating the list to ensure that in all entries `curr` and `next` are different and the same `assert` in the loop of removing elements. The second one fails!

I would appreciate if anyone can help me.

P.S. I am sorry for not being very precise but I wanted to keep the details as low as possible.

UPDATE: This is (a very simplified version of) how I erase the elements from the map:

```
while (myMap.size() > MAX_SIZE) {
    t = list.getMin();
    /* compute the merged version ... let's call the result as (a,b) */
    myMap.erase(t.curr);
    myMap.erase(t.next);
    myMap.insert(pair<double,double>(a,b));

    /* update the adjacent entries */
}
```

Comment: Please show the code where you erase the elements.

Comment: I will add the code right now.

Comment: By the way, in the shown example, `a >= t.curr->first` and `a <= t.next->first`, hence the new element would be replaced at the same place than the two erased elements.

Comment: It looks like you want something similar to a heap or tree instead of a list, so that you don't have to search for the smallest loss factor. In this case, the update of costs ln(N).

Comment: Thanks @Walter. Yes, as I mentioned, indeed the `list` I am talking of is a combination of a heap and a doubly linked list so that updates are logarithmic.

Comment: what's your "comparer" function, since using a double as a key will probably lead to not expected behaviours.

Comment: I am not using a specific compare function. Is the built-in `<` associated with doubles problematic?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684573/floating-point-keys-in-stdmap

Comment: Side note: using a `double` as a map key may produce rather surprising results. If you obtain the key values by a computation, you may get distnict keys where you'd expect indetity, simply due to precision errors.

Comment: Well, now I see where the problem is coming from: I first have to mention that the merging operation is a linear interpolation: `a = (curr->first * curr->second + next->first * next-second) / (curr->second + next->second);` and `b = curr->second + next->second`. Now, if `curr` and `next` are close in key, `a` would also be close to that key. Theoretically its value should be bigger than `curr->first` and insertion should create a new element. In practice, however, the insertion replaces the next or previous items which causes problems in the next stages.

Answer (score 0):

Stored iterators in `myPair` stay invalid after container modification. You should avoid such technique. Probably when you look into  header file you will find some ready drafts for your task?

Comment: Are you sure? Because for example in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/ it has been mentioned that the erased iterators are invalidated but the rest of iterators remain valid (in the above code, `t` is removed from the `list`).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Map iterators stay valid after container modification. But what happen when after erase myMap.erase(t.next) in our next iteration we do myMap.erase(t.curr) is it possible when t.next for first iteration is equal to t.curr in the next iteration?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have omitted a large part of the code to avoid complications. But in reality the iterators stored in `list` are updated after the `erase` operations. In particular, the `next` element of the entry which were pointing to `t.curr` (and is invalid now) will be replaced by the new inserted element (`map::insert` would return an iterator pointing to that). Likewise the `curr` element of the entry which were pointing to `t.next` will be replaced by the iterator pointing to the newly inserted element.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already by the other people, it turns out that using `double` as the key of the `map` is problematic. In particular when the values are computed.

Hence, my solution was to use `std::multimap` instead of `map` (and then merge the elements with the same key just after populating the map). With this, for example even if `a` is very close to both keys of `t.curr` and `t.next` or any other element, for sure the `insert` operation creates a new element such that no existing `iterator` in the `list` would point to that.