# Providing a good hash function

Tags: c++, stl, performance-testing, unordered-set, hash-function

In my initial question (detailed experimental investigation): [Appropriate container for the fast insertion and lookup of n-dimensional real vectors (initial benchmarking provided)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687879/appropriate-container-for-the-fast-insertion-and-lookup-of-n-dimensional-real-ve) I got really strange behaviour using the unsorted set for management of random N-dimensional float arrays with my initial (likely poor designed Hash function):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <array>
#include <unordered_set>

const int N = 3;  // Dimensionality of the arrays

std::array<double, N> getRandomArray() {
  // Engines and distributions retain state, thus defined as static
  static std::default_random_engine e;                    // engine
  static std::uniform_real_distribution<double> d(0, 1);  // distribution
  std::array<double, N> ret;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    ret[i] = d(e);
  }
  return ret;
}

// Return Squared Euclidean Distance
template <typename InputIt1, typename InputIt2>
double EuclideanDistance2(InputIt1 beg1, InputIt1 end1, InputIt2 beg2) {
  double val = 0.0;
  while (beg1 != end1) {
    double dist = (*beg1++) - (*beg2++);
    val += dist*dist;
  }
  return val;
}

struct ArrayHash {  // Hash Function
  std::size_t operator() (const std::array<double, N>& arr) const {
    std::size_t ret = 0;
    for (const double elem : arr) {
      ret += std::hash<double>()(elem);
    }
    return ret;
  }
};

struct ArrayEqual {  // Equivalence Criterion
  bool operator() (const std::array<double, N>& arr1,
                          const std::array<double, N>& arr2) const {
    return EuclideanDistance2(arr1.begin(), arr1.end(), arr2.begin()) < tol*tol;
  }
 private:
  static constexpr double tol = 1e-6;  // Comparison tolerance
};


int main() {
  // create a unordered set of double arrays (usda)
  std::unordered_set<std::array<double, N>, ArrayHash, ArrayEqual> usda;
  // record start time
  auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  // Generate and insert one hundred thousands new double arrays
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
    // Get a new random double array (da)
    std::array<double, N> da = getRandomArray();
    usda.insert(da);
  }
  // record finish time
  auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
  std::cout << "Time to generate and insert unique elements into UNORD. SET: "
            << diff.count() << " s\n";
  std::cout << "unord. set size() = " << usda.size() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Two the most strange things are:

1. Running experiments without any optimization flags even with loose tolerance (1e-1) almost all random vectors (implemented as N-dimensional arrays) were identified as unique. I haven't observed this using `vectors` and `sets`.
2. While turning on -O3 optimization flag, the number of unique elements significantly differs from the numbers without optimization and this is for sure states that there's something wrong with my approach.

**Edit:** 2-nd problem solved taking into account @WhozCraig remark.

**So, my question is**: is this strange behaviour because my hash function is badly designed? If so, can you please suggest how to make a better hash function for my case?

Comment: Have you checked what the actual hash value of a given array is? Does it change when built with -O3? Have you looked at the distribution of hash values for some manageable number of random arrays? Does -O3 select a different default random engine?

Comment: `std::size_t ret;`  you realize that thing is *indeterminate* ? Thus the follow-up looped `ret += std::hash<double>()(elem);` is pretty much worthless. So, yeah, I'd say it's badly designed.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, this was really the case (shame on me)! After initializing `std::size_t ret = 0` I got rid of 2-nd strange thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your program exhibits undefined behavior (uninitialized `std::size_t ret` variable aside).

First, `ArrayEqual` does not induce an equivalence relationship. It's not transitive - there exist three arrays `a`, `b` and `c` such that `a` is "close enough" to `b` and `b` is "close enough" to `c`, but `a` is not "close enough" to `c`.

Second, `ArrayHash` may not return the same hash value for two arrays that `ArrayEqual` declares equal.

Both of these are prerequisites on the template arguments of `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: Thanks, I fully agree with both your remarks. The practical problem now is how to fix them.

Comment: You need to define your equivalence classes, and stick to them. E.g. you could divide the space into an N-dimensional grid, `1e-6` units on a side. All points that fall into the same cell would be considered equivalent by `ArrayEqual`. Pick a representative for the class (e.g. the center of the cell, or the corner with the smallest coordinates), and have `ArrayHash` return a hash of that representative for each point in the cell.