# Custom key_comp with a class that takes an argument for a c++ set

Tags: c++, set, eigen

I've been trying to create a set of Vector3d*s* (from the Eigen Library). The set, furthermore, will take a key_comp from a custom class which happens to take an argument too. So the following is my code

```
#include <set>
#include <Eigen/Core>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

class Vector3dNormCompareClass {
public:
        Vector3dNormCompareClass(const double prec) {
                _prec = prec;
        }
        bool operator ()(const Vector3d lhs, const Vector3d rhs) const;
private:
        double _prec;
};

bool Vector3dNormCompareClass::operator ()(const Vector3d lhs,
                const Vector3d rhs) const {    
        if (lhs.norm() < rhs.norm())
                return true;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                if (abs(lhs(i) - rhs(i)) > _prec)
                        return lhs(i) < rhs(i);
        }
        return false;
}

class Tan {    
    set<Vector3d,Vector3dNormCompareClass> _transList;
    public:
    void setTransList(double foo);    
};


void Tan::setTransList(double foo) {
    Vector3dNormCompareClass comp(foo);
    _transList(comp);    
}
```

Here, `_transList` is the set I want to construct when the class `Tan` is declared and `Vector3dNormCompareClass` is the class for the `key_comp` that takes an argument for the precision of the comparison (since we're comparing the vectors of doubles). Furthermore, in my case I want to be able to reset the precision of the `key_comp`, i.e. `Vector3dNormCompareClass`, but with the current form my code, unfortunately, doesn't compile. Could anyone help me how to define the list such that it can take the custom `key_comp` with its argument (i.e. `double prec`)?

**UPDATE**
Because some of you apparently are more concerned about the mathematical validity of my `key_comp`, I have added some code in it: `if (lhs.norm() < rhs.norm()) return true;` to fulfill the condition defined [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/), I quote:

> The set object uses this expression to determine both the order the elements follow in the container and whether two element keys are equivalent (by comparing them reflexively: they are equivalent if !comp(a,b) && !comp(b,a)). No two elements in a set container can be equivalent.

So, by checking `(a<b) & (b>a)`, I believe my `key_comp` will fulfill the condition to determine equivalent keys. That said, the `double prec` here is now used to order the keys and I want to make it "flexible", meaning able to reset, perhaps, every time after I clear `_transList`, i.e. `_transList.clear()`. So my problem still exists, namely the code doesn't compile with the current form and I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this concern!

Comment: What's wrong with using a lambda expression and capture variables instead?

Comment: When do you want to _reset the precision of `key_comp`_? After `_transList` has been constructed? That is not allowed I'm afraid. Imagine you would increase `_prec`. Then, two set elements that were originally different might become equal.

Comment: @DanielLangr How about after I clear `_transList` up; i.e. `_transList.clear()`, is it possible to reset `_prec`?

Comment: @rnels12 It's even not possible to use floating-point comparator based on considering close number to be equal. See, e.g, https://stackoverflow.com/q/6684573/580083 for discussion.

Comment: IMO you need to write your own container which will be some kind of [B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree).

Comment: Your modified comparator is wrong again. Consider `a=[-0.5,0,0]` and `b=[1,0,0]`. Then `a.norm()` is 0.5 and `b.norm()` is 1. Therefore `comp(a,b)` is `true`, but `comp(b,a)` is `true` as well, since `a(0)<b(0)` is true. This break the rule that if `comp(a,b)==true` then `comp(b,a)==false`.

Comment: @DanielLangr with your example: if `comp(a,b)` is true, why is `comp(b,a)` true as well? With my code `comp(b,a)` is indeed `false`. After checking the norm, which is passed since `b.norm()` NOT < `a.norm()`, in the element-wise checking, nothing will yield `true` for `b(i) < a(i)` (btw it should be `b(i) < a(i)`) so it comes to the last line line which returns `false`. Did you do the analysis correctly?

Comment: You're right, my bad. I switched the signs. It should have been `a=[0.5,0,0]` and `b=[-1,0,0]`. `comp(a,b)==true` (the norms are the same independently of signs), but `comp(b,a)==true` as well, since `b(0)==-1<0.5==a(0)`.

Comment: Also note that with your new comparator, any two vectors will be considered `equal` only if they have the very same norm. Therefore vectors `[1,0,0]` and `[1+_prec/2.0,0,0]` will not be considered equal (at least one comparison will be true, and equal will be consequently false), even if they are "closer" to each other than `_prec`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just reset the comparator, since this would (likely) also change the internal order. You can however reset the set using a new comparator (and optionally insert the current values):

```
void Tan::setTransList(double foo) {
    Vector3dNormCompareClass comp(foo);
    set<Vector3d,Vector3dNormCompareClass> tmp(
        _transList.begin(), _transList.end(), // remove this line if you don't want to copy old entries
        comp); 
    _transList.swap(tmp);    
}
```

**Edit:** As Daniel pointed out, your comparator does not fulfill the necessary criteria for a set (namely being transitive), i.e., you will likely get unexpected results (depending on the order you insert values).

Comment: I have added some codes to fulfill the condition defined in: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/, namely: keys are equivalent if !comp(a,b) && !comp(b,a).

Comment: Your solution seems to work; the code compiles. Now I'm gonna see if it works with my full code. I upvote your answer but will also wait a bit longer to accept this as the answer, in case some can come up with with a bit more elegant solution. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you cannot define a comparator for associative containers this way in case of floating-point keys. The C++ Standard requires that equality derived from comparator is transitive, such as: [`equiv(a, b) && equiv(b, c)` implies `equiv(a, c)`](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sorting#4.2), where `equiv(a, b)` is defined as [`!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sorting#4).

With floating-point keys and comparing with respect to some precision, you can get `equiv(a, b)` and `equiv(b, c)` being `true` (both differ of less than the precision) but `equiv(a, c)` being `false` (sum of the differences is higher than the precision).

---

**Example for scalar keys**

Consider `_prec` being 0.1 (it's high for exemplary purposes, you can make the same analysis for any value). Then `comp(a, b)` being defined as `abs(a, b) < 0.1` will imply that `equiv(1.10, 1.19)` is `true` as well as `equiv(1.19, 1.28)`, but `equiv(1.10, 1.28)` will be `false`.

Comment: That is true, although this is not the reason for the code not compiling.

Comment: I agree with @chtz, my main concern is about the code to compile. Also, according to this page: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/, `a and b are equivalent if !comp(a,b) && !comp(b,a)).` How about I first check (a<b) and (b<a), certainly if they are the same numbers they will fulfill this condition. (I added this in my code) So in this case the `prec` is just used to order the key. Then my question remains, how to make the code compile to allow with this flexible precision?

Comment: @rnels12 If you read further, you'll see that the comparison also needs to fulfill "strict weak ordering" -- look up what that means, if you don't want to get surprised later.