# std::set custom compare function for double values. insert() does not work

Tags: c++, stdset

I created a set via

```
bool(*fn_pt)(const double&, const double&) = comp_double;
std::set<double, bool(*)(const double&, const double&) > values(fn_pt);
```

where my comp_double function is given by

```
bool comp_double (const double& p1, const double& p2)
{
return (std::abs(p1-p2)<1e-05);
}
```

I inserted two dummy elements, values.insert(0.01) and values.insert(0.02), but the size of my set is still zero.
There are no compiler warnings or errors, so I guess the problem lies within my comp_double function. Any input would be appreciated!

Best

Comment: `std::set` requires "less" instead of "equal" anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First, we should remember that a `std::set` is an **associative container** *(that contains only the "keys")*. Yes, we can provide our own comparison operation for an associative container. This operation must conform to strict weak ordering (we can think of it as a **"less than"**), means to have the following properties:

- Two keys cannot be both "less than" each other. (Also, a key cannot yield "less" with itself)
- The comparison has to be transitive. If `key1 < key2`, `key2 < key3`, then `key1 < key3`
- If we have two keys and neither of these is "less than" the other, they must be equivalent.

Consider this case:

```
key1 = 0.000001;
key2 = 0.000002;

abs(key1 - key2) == 0.000001; // which is less than 0.00001, true
abs(key2 - key1) == 0.000001; // same, true too
```

Each of them is "less" than the other, means they violate the first constraint. Also, a key here will **yield true for "less" with itself**.

You may want to take a look at: [Does using epsilon in comparison of floating-point break strict-weak-ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68114060/does-using-epsilon-in-comparison-of-floating-point-break-strict-weak-ordering)

For more on the requirements on a `Compare` check the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare#Requirements).

Comment: `s/equal/equivalent/` and you miss some constraints.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks! May you please specify which?

Comment: There are 4 on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) linked from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare).

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback. I thought so that my comparison using std::abs is too simple. However for my purposes as engineer I always compared double values with an epsilon threshold. So can you give me some keywords how my comparison should look like?

Comment: @Simon you should take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68114060/does-using-epsilon-in-comparison-of-floating-point-break-strict-weak-ordering) if you haven't yet seen it. Especially this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68114287/14624729). Feel free to comment or initiate a fresh question on the topic.