# map with double keys C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures

I have different stocks with their prices and I want to store them in the, for example std::map or std::unordered_map:

```
struct Stock
{
    ...
};

using stock_price_t = double;

std::map<stock_price_t, Stock> ordered_stocks;
std::unordered_map<stock_price_t, Stock> unordered_stocks;
```

Is it good idea use double keys in the dictionaries or better solutions is present?

Comment: What does your Stock structure look like? Better to use something else for key, maybe some kind of stock ID.

Comment: You run the risk of losing stuff e.g. adding a key with value (0.1 + 0.2) then looking up key 0.3 might claim it's not there. Also, why do you need to lookup the price?

Comment: indepenent of the map you shouldn't use floating point numbers for prices or currencies.

Comment: (To add to what others have said, take a look at https://0.30000000000000004.com/)

Comment: This thread could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684573/floating-point-keys-in-stdmap

Comment: As another approach, I feel like the price of a stock should go into the `Stock` structure, Then you can use a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` to store your stocks (or a sorted `std::vector` if you want random access and fast iteration). You can use compare functions that `std::lower_bound` or other `std` functions take in to find your stocks (since you are using floating-points, you can use marginal comparison `std::abs(A - B) < epsilon`).

Comment: another thing is that you shouldn't use floating-point for money. Store the cent value in integer instead, which will also help using it as a key easily

Comment: A good way to store ordered book of stocks is `boost::multi_index` container indexed by stock id and sorted by price. If you need to erase a stock you can look up by id index. If you need to traverse from the lowest price to the highest you can traverse by ordered price index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::map` has no issue with using `double`s as key. It uses `<` to compare keys and two keys are equivalent when `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`. That's fine. The issues do arise when you expect floating point numbers to be exact when in fact they are not.

For example:

```
std::map<double,int> m{{0.3,0},{1.0,2},{2.0,2},{3.0,3}};
for (const auto& e : m) std::cout << e.first << " " << e.second << "\n";
```

Output is:

```
0.3 0
1 2
2 2
3 3
```

But now consider this:

```
auto it = m.find(0.1 + 0.2);
if (it == m.end()) std::cout << "not found\n";
```

Searching `0.1 + 0.2` will not find the key `0.3`, because `double`s are not exact and the output is

```
not found
```

TL;DR: Do not use floating point numbers for prices or currencies. When you need prices with cents then use `int` cents:

```
std::map<int, Stock> ordered_stocks;
for (const auto& e : ordered_stocks) {
      std::cout << "dollars: " << e.first / 100 << "\n";
      std::cout << "stock: " << e.second << "\n";
}
```