# Conditional Averaging of a vector based on similarities in another vector c++

Tags: c++, vector, conditional-statements, average

It is best to give an example.

Let's say vector A consists of:

```
A = {3  ,2 ,1 ,4  ,6 ,3 ,8 ,4}
```

and vector B consists of:

```
B = {1.5,2 ,2 ,1.5,3 ,3 ,3 ,2}
```

The unique values in vector B are `{1.5, 2, 3}`

I want the resulting vector RESULT to be:

```
RESULT[0] = Average(A given B=1.5) = Average(3,4)

RESULT[1] = Average(A given B=2 )  = Average(2,1,4)

RESULT[2] = Average(A given B=3 )  = Average(6,3,8)
```

What is the most efficient way of calculating this. My own method is to loop over unique elements of B, and for each of them, loop over each B value trying to match that unique number and keep summing up the corresponding element of vector A in each match, also counting the number of matches so I can find the average.

This is too slow. since My vector A is 8M elements, and vector B consists of 0.5M unique values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sort both vectors in lockstep and then iterate over equal-ranges of `B`?

Comment: That seems promising, I will try it out now to see how much speed improvement I can get.

Comment: It's a smell to depend on exact equality of floating point values though.

Comment: Unique values with floating point numbers sounds strange. Be aware that e.g. `.1+.2!=.3` with `double`s.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a lazy idea: Traverse both vectors in lockstep and aggregate the results in a separate container. For example:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

std::map<double, std::pair<int, std::size_t>> m;

assert(A.size() == B.size());

for (std::size_t i = 0; i != A.size(); ++i)
{
    assert(!std::isnan(B[i]));

    auto & p = m[B[i]];
    p.first += A[i];
    p.second += 1;
}
```

In the end you just report the results:

```
for (const auto & p : m)
    std::cout << "Average for bin " << p.first << " is "
              << static_cast<double>(p.second.first) / p.second.second
              << "\n";
```

(Beware that your key value must not be NaN: in an ordered map, NaN is not part of the strict ordering; in an unordered map, it does not compare equal to itself.)

Comment: Why use a `map` instead of an `unordered_map`?

Comment: @DDrmmr: Ordered traversal for reporting?

Comment: Nice touch to assert !isnan :) I remember to SO question (+1)

Comment: Thanks, this method looks good. I will try this as well. I didn't know "auto & p = m[B[i]];" would automatically take care of the map. Nice! and no, my data do not have any NaNs.

Comment: @sehe: I seem to remember having seen [a question about this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8096817/596781) :-)

Comment: Of course, using a proper struct instead of the std::pair does make my answer a bit more expressive `average_state[B[i]].sample(A[i]);` FTW :)

Comment: @sehe: I'm pretty surprised you managed to answer this without any reference to Boost Phoenix, Qi, Karma, or MPL sequences. Not even any Fusion...

Comment: @KerrekSB Hey! Just the fact that I use tag [tag:boost] to make a dent in learning the boost libraries, doesn't mean I can't do things without it (it just means I have to focus - there's not enough time to more than just these tags :))

Comment: @sehe: Hm, well, for once I was actually hoping you could whip out some magic zip iterator that allows the simultaneous sorting that I suggested in the comment above. It might be nice to also have a solution that requires no extra space...

Comment: @KerrekSB I pondered about abusing `std::transform` (in binary form). But I thought it abuse. Also, you could look at Boost Accumulators if you're looking for some extra fidelities (and compile time) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a loop with a (hash) table: see it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d56a8b9bce33836)**

```
int main()
{
    vector<int>    A = {3  ,2 ,1 ,4  ,6 ,3 ,8 ,4};
    vector<double> B = {1.5,2 ,2 ,1.5,3 ,3 ,3 ,2};

    assert(A.size() == B.size());

    struct accum { 
        uintmax_t sum = 0; 
        size_t number_of_samples = 0; 
        void sample(int val) { sum += val; ++number_of_samples; }
    };
    map<double, accum> average_state;

    for(size_t i = 0; i<B.size(); ++i)
        average_state[B[i]].sample(A[i]);

    for(auto& entry : average_state)
    {
        accum& state = entry.second;
        double average = static_cast<double>(state.sum) / state.number_of_samples;
        std::cout << "Bucket " << entry.first << "\taverage of " << state.number_of_samples << " samples:\t" << average << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Bucket 1.5  average of 2 samples:   3.5
Bucket 2    average of 3 samples:   2.33333
Bucket 3    average of 3 samples:   5.66667
```

Comment: why is the average called effective?

Comment: because it's calculated. You can name it "average" of course. I have no idea about the problem domain so I made something up. **updated**