# calling .clear() or .erase() on c++ std::multimap sometimes causes freeze (100% cpu)

Tags: c++, multimap, erase

We are using a multimap for quick value/index lookups, declared like this

```
typedef double Numerical;
std::multimap<Numerical, Int32> SortableRowIndex;
```

And we fill it up with pairs, using

```
SortableRowIndex.insert(std::pair<Numerical, Int32>(GetSortable(i), i));
```

The function GetSortable() always returns a double. And this works fine. Iterating through the values works fine too. But then comes the weird part... sometimes when we try to clear the data...

```
SortableRowIndex.clear();
```

... it goes into some kind of loop and stalls/races, hogging the used core of the CPU at 100%.

The clear method seems to be inherited from xtree (system file) and there are only a coupld of rows inside it:

```
    void clear() _NOEXCEPT
        {   // erase all
 #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
        this->_Orphan_ptr(*this, 0);
 #endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2 */

        _Erase(_Root());
        _Root() = this->_Myhead;
        _Lmost() = this->_Myhead;
        _Rmost() = this->_Myhead;
        this->_Mysize = 0;
        }
```

For some reason, my Visual Studio 2013 won't let me step into this method when debugging... and I can't, for the life of me figure out what the problem is!

Any help will be ridiculously appreciated!

Comment: Are there any NaNs in the input?

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096817/is-nan-a-valid-key-value-for-associative-containers can be related

Comment: Trying to figure out what you mean... input to where?

Comment: Oh, thanks for the link... I don't think there should be any NaNs in there, but I'll write some code to verify it! Thanks.

Comment: I did a std::isnan() check on all the keys going in, and none returned true. I am also able to insert new keys and iterate over the data.

Comment: I'm considering trying the multimap in boost... maybe it behaves differently?

Comment: I'll try to create an example, but the data I'm inserting is around 1.7 million pairs.... btw this works: 

auto it = SortableRowIndex.begin();
while (it != SortableRowIndex.end())
 it = SortableRowIndex.erase(it);

but is REALLY slow!

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, it's not really stalling, but clearing a multimap through Visual Studio's debugger is REALLY SLOW. I noticed that the memory was getting released slooowly and let it run for a couple of minutes and then it was finally done. Running the application outside of Visual Studio made the .clear() calls drop down to < 1s, even for millions of pairs.

So, heads up if you are clearing huge multimaps while running in debug mode in visual studio. It's sloooooow.

Comment: Appearently Release mode is just as slow if you launch it trough Visual Studio's debugger.