# Why does std::rel_ops need equality operator?

Tags: c++, operators, std, equality

Why is equality needed for rel_ops?
Isn't "<" enough?

`a==b => !(a<b) && !(b<a)`

It might be a very stupid question. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, if the standard did that, it will make things like `NaN` equal to `NaN`, which is debatable... And No, you cannot exactly compare this with how `std::map` finds a key. Because the domain for the [key has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096817/is-nan-a-valid-key-value-for-associative-containers) constraints

Comment: Not quite about `rel_ops`, but this has been a hot topic with `<=>`. You can read more in papers ([`<=> != ==`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1185r0.html), [I did not order this! Why is it on my bill?](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1190r0.html)) and blogs ([Improvements to <=>](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2018/11/12/improve-spaceship/)). For reference, `<=>` has already been changed because of this.

Comment: @chris: Thanks! Very interesting read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is equality needed for rel_ops? Isn't "<" enough?
>
> ```
> a==b => !(a<b) && !(b<a)
> ```

Because this is not true in general. If `rel_ops` would work only for relational operators that follow that logic it would be rather limited.

I guess what you have in mind is the weak ordering required for the `<` operator for associative containers. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

> Everywhere the standard library uses the Compare requirements,
>   uniqueness is determined by using the equivalence relation. In
>   imprecise terms, two objects a and b are considered equivalent (not
>   unique) if neither compares less than the other: !comp(a, b) &&
>   !comp(b, a).

In simple terms: Whether two keys are considered the "same" is only determined by requiring `! (a < b) && ! (b < a)`. Hence you only need to supply a `<` for associative containers and no `operator==` to decide whether two keys are the same. However, equivalence (`!(a<b)&&!(b<a)`) is not necessarily the same as equality (`a==b`).

For example when you use this

```
struct my_key {
    int a;
    int b;
    bool operator< (const key_type& other) {
        return a < other.a;   // not comparing b !
    }
};
```

as a key of a `std::map` then `my_key{1,0}` and `my_key{1,2}` are equivalent ("same key"), even though they are not equal. As another example, consider a `Point` in spherical coordinates where we choose to have `a < b` when `a` is closer to the origin than `b`:

```
struct Point {
    double radius;
    double angle;
    bool operator<(const Point& other) { 
        return radius < other.radius; 
    }
    bool operator==(const Point& other) {
        return (radius == other.radius) && (angle == other.angle);
    }
}
```

Also here all three `a < b`,`b < a` and `a == b` can be false at the same time.

Also note that (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp))

> As of C++20, std::rel_ops are deprecated in favor of operator<=>.

For the [starship operator `<=>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons) you can choose between

```
std::strong_ordering 
std::weak_ordering
std::partial_ordering
std::strong_equality 
std::weak_equality
```

Weak ordering is what is required eg for `std::map` (eg `my_key` or `Point`), while for strong ordering equivalence and equality are basically the same. For more details and examples I refer you to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I dont remember why i put it there, it wasnt relevant for the example.

Comment: It's not true either :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah, I know ;), its not the best example, still I wanted to keep it

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually started wondering about this starting from a task requiring std::map.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually you are missing sth. And it is very fundamental. It is not about C++ or programing. It's about math. According to math, your statement is true if and only if  "<" defines a strict [weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering?wprov=sfla1) on its operand domain. Not every user-defined type with "less" rel_op has a weak ordering.