# std::minmax_element comparer for a vector with std::optional is incorrect

Tags: c++, vector, minmax, stdoptional

I have a struct within a struct of std::optionals, and I am trying to find the minimum and maximum value within the struct. However, using std::minmax_element seems to be inaccurate, and I've had to split the comparison function and use std::min_element and std::max_element instead. Is there a way to approach this that will allow me to still use std::minmax_element and be cleaner?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <optional>
#include <algorithm>

struct AE
{
    double A;
    double E;
};

struct HM
{
   std::optional<AE> H;
   std::optional<AE> M;
};


bool CompareHM(const HM& a_, const HM& b_)
{
    // If both H fields have a value, compare them by A
    if (a_.H.has_value() && b_.H.has_value()) 
    {
        return a_.H->A < b_.H->A;
    }
    // If only one H field has a value, set to false
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool CompareHMMax(const HM& a_, const HM& b_)
{
    // If both H fields have a value, compare them by A
    if (a_.H.has_value() && b_.H.has_value()) 
    {
        return a_.H->A < b_.H->A;
    }
    // If only one H field has a value, consider it larger
    else if (a_.H.has_value()) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    // If both H fields are empty, or if just b has a value
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool CompareHMMin(const HM& a_, const HM& b_)
{
    // If both H fields have a value, compare them by A
    if (a_.H.has_value() && b_.H.has_value()) 
    {
        return a_.H->A < b_.H->A;
    }
    // If only one H field has a value, consider it smaller
    else if (a_.H.has_value()) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    // If both H fields are empty, or if just b has a value
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Create a vector of HM structs with some data
    std::vector<HM> vec = {
        HM{AE{1.8, 4.5}, AE{7.2, 4.1}},
        HM{AE{2.3, 3.4}, std::nullopt},
        HM{std::nullopt, AE{6.7, 8.9}},
        HM{AE{0.9, 2.1}, std::nullopt},
        HM{AE{1.8, 4.2}, AE{7.6, 9.0}},
        HM{std::nullopt, AE{0.7, 13.5}},
        HM{std::nullopt, AE{0.5, 19.3}},
        HM{AE{2.1, 4.2}, std::nullopt},
    };

    auto minmax = std::minmax_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(), CompareHM);
    auto min = std::min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(), CompareHMMin);
    auto max = std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(), CompareHMMax);

    // Print the results
    std::cout << "Correct Min A value: " << min->H->A << "\n";
    std::cout << "Correct Max A value: " << max->H->A << "\n";
    std::cout << "Incorrect Min A value using minmax_element: " << minmax.first->H->A << "\n";
    std::cout << "Incorrect Max A value using minmax_element: " << minmax.second->H->A << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Correct Min A value: 0.9
Correct Max A value: 2.3
Incorrect Min A value using minmax_element: 1.8
Incorrect Max A value using minmax_element: 2.1
```

Comment: No it is a correct result, you don't have a strict ordening (when both items are not set).  See requirements for [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). It must result in a [total stict ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Strict_and_non-strict_total_orders)

Comment: You are contradicting yourself: *If only one H field has a value, consider it smaller* and *or if just b has a value* both return false in `HMMax`

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer, what I'm getting is that to achieve a sensible comparison for all Hs, I must filter out any non-valid H elements. Then I could use std::minmax_element and make this a much simpler comparison, correct?

Comment: @PepijnKramer that is incorrect. A *Compare* needs to be a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings).

Comment: @Brinck Yes.  If you have access to C++20 you can create a [filter view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view) and then run you search on that filtered view.

Comment: @JanSchultke You are correct, I scanned to quickly... there is a "strict ordering" comment later on the page which I copied... it should indeed have been the weak ordering earlier on the page.

Comment: @JanSchultke I believe you in fact can't sort NaNs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096817/is-nan-a-valid-key-value-for-associative-containers

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike Darn, I only have C++17 accessible to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CompareHM` does not induce a [*strict weak ordering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings), which is why `std::minmax_element` gives you nonsense results.

A strict weak ordering needs to be transitive, and incomparable elements break this:

> ```cpp
> a < std::nullopt && std::nullopt < b   =>   a < b
> ```

This implication needs to be true for a *strict weak ordering*, but clearly isn't when `std::nullopt` is incomparable.

Incomparability needs to be a transitive relationship, i.e.

> ```cpp
> a incomparable_to std::nullopt  &&  b incomparable_to  =>  a incomparable_to b
> ```

But this is clearly not the case if `a` is comparable to `b`.
On a side note this is also why you cannot sort ranges of `float`s that contain NaN (see [Is NaN a valid key value for associative containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8096817/5740428)).

Unlike in your `Min` and `Max` relations, we cannot simply treat `std::nullopt` as a positive/negative infinity value.

#### C++17 or Older

In older C++ standards, you could eliminate `std::nullopt` elements in-place using `std::remove_if` in the remove-erase idiom:

```cpp
vec.erase(std::remove_if([](const HM& h) {
    return !h.has_value();
}, vec.end());
auto minmax = std::minmax_element(vec);
std::cout << minmax.first->H->A << ' ' << minmax.second->H->A << '\n';
```

Actually, it would be sufficient to use just `std::remove_if` if your goal is only to find the minimum and maximum element.
Obviously, there's always the option of using `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` separately.

#### C++20

We could use `std::ranges::filter_view` to get a view of our range without any `std::nullopt` elements inside, allowing `std::ranges::minmax_element` to work correctly.

```cpp
auto filter = std::ranges::filter_view(vec, [](const HM& h) {
    return h.H.has_value();
});

auto minmax = std::ranges::minmax_element(filter, CompareHM);
std::cout << minmax.min->H->A << ' ' << minmax.max->H->A << '\n';
```

Comment: One up for `ranges::filter_view` - I always forget about the power of ranges :-)

Answer (score 3):

A big problem is that in order to use `std::minmax_element` you need to decide if a valueless `optional` should be greater or less than an optional with a value. It can't be both. A simple solution is to exclude the `HM`s where `H` is valueless by partitioning the `vector` first.

You could also `default` `operator<=>` to make this simpler. For `optional`:

- The contained values are compared (using the corresponding operator of `T`) only if both lhs and rhs contain values. Otherwise,
- lhs is considered equal to rhs if, and only if, both lhs and rhs do not contain a value.
- lhs is considered less than rhs if, and only if, rhs contains a value and lhs does not.

That works fine with algorithms requiring *strict week ordering*, so:

```cpp
struct AE {
    double A;
    double E;
    
    auto operator<=>(const AE& other) const = default;
};

struct HM {
    std::optional<AE> H;
    std::optional<AE> M;

    auto operator<=>(const HM&) const = default;
};
```

Then partition the `vector` to put the `HM`s with a valueless `H` last in the `vector`:

```cpp
auto pp = std::stable_partition(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](auto&& hm) {
    return hm.H.has_value();
});
```

Then `minmax_element` can do its job:

```cpp
auto [min, max] = std::minmax_element(vec.begin(), pp);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e1Y45dhEn)

If you don't want to partition the `vector` you can also use a `ranges::filter_view` like [Jan showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76509530/7582247), except that you'd exclude the custom comparator.

---

In C++17 and older you could define `operator<` for the two classes in order for the simplification to work. Still no need for the complicated custom comparators:

```cpp
struct AE {
    double A;
    double E;

    bool operator<(const AE& other) const {
        return std::tie(A, E) < std::tie(other.A, other.E);
    }
};

struct HM {
    std::optional<AE> H;
    std::optional<AE> M;

    bool operator<(const HM& other) const {
        return std::tie(H, M) < std::tie(other.H, other.M);
    }
};
```

Partitioning and calling `minmax_element` would work the same as above.