# When to use C float comparison functions?

Tags: c++, c, c++11

In the latest C++ standard, I noticed the following macros :

```
bool isgreater(float x, float y);
bool isgreaterequal(float x, float y);
bool isless(float x, float y);
bool islessequal(float x, float y);
bool islessgreater(float x, float y);
bool isunordered(float x, float y);
```

These macros are from C (7.12.14 and 7.12.14).

So, why would someone use these macros, instead of operators? Is there anything special that these macros are doing (like checking for `inf`), or are they the same as their corresponding operator?

C++ example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
  float x=0.2;
  float y=0.5;
  std::cout << x << " < " << y << " : " << std::boolalpha << std::islessequal( x, y ) << std::endl;
  std::cout << x << " < " << y << " : " << std::boolalpha << ( x <= y ) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Unlike the relational operators, these macros do really only return a boolean value and do never raise any floating point exception.

In short: You only have to deal with `true`/`false` and nothing else.

---

*references*:

**The Open Group** descriptions (*not the C or C++ standard, but highly relevant in the Unix/Linux world and almost always similar to the standards*):

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/islessgreater.html
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isgreater.html
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isgreaterequal.html
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isless.html
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/islessequal.html
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/islessgreater.html
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isunordered.html

**C++** standard:

> #### C Library [c.math]:
>
> The classification/comparison functions behave the same as the C macros with the corresponding names defined in 7.12.3, Classification macros, and 7.12.14, Comparison macros in the C Standard. Each function is overloaded for the three floating-point types, as follows [...]

**C** standard:

> #### 7.12.14 Comparison macros
>
> [...] For any ordered pair of numeric values exactly one of the
>   relationships — less, greater, and equal — is true. Relational **operators** may raise the
>   ‘‘invalid’’ floating-point exception when argument values are NaNs. **For a NaN and a
>   numeric value, or for two NaNs, just the unordered relationship is true**.
>   The following subclauses provide macros that are quiet (non floating-point exception raising) versions of the relational operators, and other comparison macros that facilitate **writing efficient code that accounts for NaNs without suffering the ‘‘invalid’’ floating-point exception**. In
>   the synopses in this subclause, real-floating indicates that the argument shall be an
>   expression of real floating type.

Comment: I.e. we _still_ don't have a valid predicate for `std::set<float>` other than the rather useless `isunordered`. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816156/are-ieee-floats-valid-key-types-for-stdmap-and-stdset why)

Comment: @MSalters: I love macros, too, no rly.

Comment: It's not a macro problem (they're not even macro's in C++). The functions fail to define a strict weak ordering for `NaN`. They just remove the exception, but that doesn't make the result useful enough.

Comment: Yeah, missed the part about that being functions in C++ :P But I realised the ordering problem, too.

Answer (score 14):

`isgreater` et al. were incorporated into C++11 from C99.  They are defined to not raise the invalid floating-point exception when `x` and/or `y` are signalling `NaN` values.

The rationale given is:

> This macro is a quiet (non-floating-point exception raising) version of a relational operator. It facilitates writing efficient code that accounts for NaNs without suffering the invalid floating-point exception.

The numeric value of the macro on `NaN` is the same as always; `NaN` values compare false to  all other values including `NaN` values under all relational operators and the new macros.