# Binary Search on template floats C++

Tags: c++

I have been tasked to write a binary search for an array of floating point values that will report the same answer even when run on various hardware platforms or with different compilers. Also, provide a template which provides the binary search algorithm for any provided data type.

So, I wrote this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>

bool bsearch(T num)
{
    T arr[] = {5.3, 6.62, 7.74, 10.22, 13.22};
    int len = (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));
    int mid, l_bound=0, u_bound = len-1;
    while (l_bound <= u_bound)
    {
        mid =(l_bound+u_bound)/2;
        if (num > arr[mid])
            l_bound = mid+1;
        else if (num < arr[mid])
            u_bound = mid -1;
        else
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    float num;
    cout <<"Number to search: ";
    cin >>num;
    if (bsearch(num) == true)
        cout <<"Number found!\n";
    else
        cout <<"Nubmer not found!\n";

}
```

This works on my machine for finding the floats in the array.
My question: Does this look like it would satisfy the requirements? How do I know that this will work on other hardware platforms? Did I correctly provide the templating for this problem right?

Comment: The task is pretty stupid as it entirely forgets that you shouldn't compare floating-point values for equality unless it's bit-equality you're interested in (which it's not)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I would concur if there were invokes of `operator ==`. But if there is an equivalence comparison in this code, I don't see it. I see only `operator <` and `operator >` (which I would not do anyway; I would use two `operator <`, the second surrounded by logical-not).

Comment: @WhozCraig: If the failure cases are `operator<` and `operator>` (which they are), then what is left to count as success, other than an implicit `operator==`.....? We tend to use the algebraic system in which `!(a<b) && !(a>b) == (a==b)`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit when *neither* are true. I.e. the standard swo: `!((a<b) || (b<a))` implies `a == b`. Or did I utterly misunderstand your question? edit: you finished that as I was typing mine. And yes, that is exactly what I was referring two. I see nothing in the OP's code that directly compares two floating point values for equality, which is why I don't understand your first comment saying, ".. you shouldn't compare floating-point values for equality..", as I see no such comparison.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, that's the same equivalence I just wrote, with the `!` moved to the outside and one of the `<` flipped around to be `>`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws And I suspect you're misunderstanding the code o.O

Comment: @WhozCraig: So what if there's no direct call to `operator==`? The algorithm continues for as long as `a<b` or `b<a`. It returns `true` in the `else` clause, i.e. when neither of those things are true. And, as we've just discussed, that's `a==b`. That's _literally equivalent to performing a check for `operator==`_. What else would a binary search do? The point is that there is no consideration here for the inherent imprecision of many floating-point values. I expect it to return `false` for a whole range of inputs for which it should not.

Comment: Outside of NaN (which I concur should be accounted for) I'm pressed to fathom where a swo comparison chain would *break*, but I'm truly interested if such a thing exists. If you can proffer up an example, that would be stellar (or link). My whole point was *I completely agree with your statement*, I just don't see it actually be *done* in the posted code.

Comment: For anyone that cares, [link to topic of SWO for floating point and fairly stellar set of responses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816156/are-ieee-floats-valid-key-types-for-stdmap-and-stdset).

Answer (score 1):

No, the function should accept the array as well as the searched value.

```
template<typename T>
bool bsearch(T* begin, T* end, T num){
    auto len = end - begin;
```

for example.

Read this in the voice of David Attenborough:

```
int main()
{
    float num;
    cout <<"Number to search: ";
    cin >>num;
    float array_to_search_in[] = {5.3, 6.62, 7.74, 10.22, 13.22};
    bool search_result = bsearch(array_to_search_in, array_to_search_in +5, num);
    if (search_result == true)...
```

Comment: So, would T* begin be the array {5.3, 6.62, 7.74, 10.22, 13.22}? What would T* end be?

Comment: begin would be `arr` end would be `arr + size`.

Comment: I'm confused by how I would implement this in my bsearch. Could you update your post with how the code would look inside the function bsearch?

Comment: @JakeSmith Have a look.

Comment: The wording of @JakeSmith 's request puts Captain Giraffe in an interesting position as the bulk of his recommendations go *outside* of the function. Let's see how the willy captain of the savannah escapes from this predicament... (This comment sounds best when read by David Attenborough)

Comment: You're confused because Captain Giraffe said "accept the array", when in fact it accepts two pointers, one to the first element and another to the last element.