# To which elements must the C++ requirement "Compare" apply?

Tags: c++, comparator, stdset

To use a comparison operator for `std::set` (and many other data structures of course), it has to fulfil the `Compare` requirement, which is expressed as certain properties for keys `a`,`b`,`c`. (Crucially, in this case, `equiv(a,b)` and `equiv(b,c)` ⇒ `equiv(a,c)`.)

Now presumably this only needs to hold for keys that I will actually give to any `std::set` methods (otherwise I could theoretically add `assert` calls to my comparison operator to allow only a subset of possible keys). But does this subset of keys have to remain constant over the lifetime of my object or even at compile-time?
Or would the following be valid for elements `a`,`b`,`c` with `a` < `c` but no other relations?

```
std::set<CuriousKey, std::less<>> set = {b};
set.find(a);
set.find(c);
```

For context, my keys are integer intervals (with some extra data), and my code looks something like this:

```
#include <set>
#include <cassert>

struct IntervalWithTag {
        using Tag = char;

    int min;
    int max;
    Tag tag; // we don't want overlapping intervals with different tags.
};

constexpr bool operator<(IntervalWithTag const& lhs, IntervalWithTag const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.max < rhs.min;
}
constexpr bool operator<(int const lhs, IntervalWithTag const& rhs)
{
    return lhs < rhs.min;
}
constexpr bool operator<(IntervalWithTag const& lhs, int const rhs)
{
    return lhs.max < rhs;
}

struct IntervalWithTagSet {
    void add_interval(IntervalWithTag interval);

    std::set<IntervalWithTag, std::less<>> intervals;
};

void IntervalWithTagSet::add_interval(IntervalWithTag interval)
{
    // find all intersecting intervals
    auto const lb = intervals.lower_bound(interval.min);
    auto const ub = intervals.upper_bound(interval.max);

    // gobble up intersecting intervals
    for (auto it = lb; it != ub; ++it) {
        assert(it->tag == interval.tag);
        interval.min = std::min(interval.min, it->min);
        interval.max = std::max(interval.max, it->max);
    }

    intervals.insert(intervals.erase(lb, ub), interval);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        IntervalWithTagSet set;

        // Add three disjoint intervals; nothing interesting happening yet
        set.add_interval({0, 1, 'a'});
        set.add_interval({2, 3, 'a'});
        set.add_interval({4, 5, 'b'});

        // Add interval [1,2], which should leave us with intervals [0,3] and [4,5]
        // Is this undefined behaviour?
        set.add_interval({1, 2, 'a'});
}
```

Using `auto const [lb, ub] = intervals.equal_range(interval)` in `IntervalWithNetSet::add_interval` would definitely technically violate the `Compare` requirement as soon as `interval` intersects more than one existing interval, but I'm unsure about my code as it stands above.

Comment: @RichardCritten It compiles now, thanks :)

Comment: I suspect that it's formally undefined behavior, but in practice you are likely to get away with it. **[associative.reqmts]/2** says that the comparator "induces a strict
weak ordering on elements of `Key`." It's not immediately clear what "elements of `Key`" means; I can't think of any other reading than "all possible values of `Key`" (as in, a type is a set of possible values; so elements of type are its possible values). In practice, in any given member function, `set` would only have a chance to compare keys already held and keys passed as parameters, so wouldn't notice anything funny.

Comment: Looks like a variant of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816156/are-ieee-floats-valid-key-types-for-stdmap-and-stdset, but you'd have to know that `NaN` floats violate the same `Compare` requirement. Also, that question predates `Compare`.